# Java streaming options to merge the list of string on the same map object

Tags: collections, java-8

I have use case to get the distinct value from the map. Is there any way using streams

```
Sample Model data set = {"Ford":{"hatchback", "sedan", "TEST"}, "Honda":{"hatchback", "sedan"}, "Toyota":{"hatchback", "sedan", "TeST2"}}

for (Entry<String, Set<String>> model: models.entrySet()) {
modelList.addAll(model.getValue()); 
}


Final List: {"hatchback", "sedan", "TEST", "TeST2"}
```

Comment: When you say “final list”, do you literally mean a *List* (of distinct values), or could it be a *Set* (which always has distinct values)?

Comment: You should provide real code instead of this pseudo code/JSON mix, to allow readers to recognize what actual types the variables have. Further, you should describe the logic that leads to the desired result instead of just giving one example. Otherwise, `finalList = Arrays.asList("hatchback", "sedan", "TEST", "TeST2")` is a valid solution to your problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .flatMap() and .collect() like this

Preparation of Data just to showcase:

```
    HashMap<String, Set<String>> models = new HashMap<>();
    models.put("Ford", Set.of("hatchback", "sedan", "TEST"));
    models.put("Honda", Set.of("hatchback", "sedan"));
    models.put("Toyota", Set.of("hatchback", "sedan", "TeST2"));
```

Usage of .flatMap() and .collect() on a stream

```
    Set<String> uniqueModels = models.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // This will print "[TEST, sedan, hatchback, TeST2]"
    System.out.println(uniqueModels);
```

Comment: Condition here is that it should be one map... do you recommend to split into n Map.Entry?

Comment: @Praveen No, I adjusted my answer to your Input. Just use models.entrySet().stream() and it should work. If it helps I would appreciate an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<String> unique=set.stream().flatMap(map->map.values().stream()).flatMap(list->list.stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```